# Compile MonoDevelop 4.2.3

Tags: linux, build, compilation, mono, monodevelop

I need help, I'm trying to compile monodevelop code, but when I use the command "./configure" tells me that I need to have installed a version of mono, but  I have it installed

```
    [raven@localhost ~]$ mono -V
    Mono JIT compiler version 3.2.8 (tarball Fri May 30 08:15:47 CDT 2014)
    Copyright (C) 2002-2014 Novell, Inc, Xamarin Inc and Contributors. www.mono-project.com
        TLS:           __thread
        SIGSEGV:       altstack
        Notifications: epoll
        Architecture:  amd64
        Disabled:      none
        Misc:          softdebug 
        LLVM:          supported, not enabled.
        GC:            sgen
    [raven@localhost ~]$ cd /home/raven/Downloads/monodevelop-4.2.3
    [raven@localhost monodevelop-4.2.3]$ ./configure
    checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
    checking whether build environment is sane... yes
    checking for a thread-safe mkdir -p... /usr/bin/mkdir -p
    checking for gawk... gawk
    checking whether make sets $(MAKE)... yes
    checking how to create a ustar tar archive... gnutar
    checking whether to enable maintainer-specific portions of Makefiles... no
    checking for mono... /usr/local/bin/mono
    checking for gmcs... /usr/local/bin/gmcs
    checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
    configure: error: You need mono 3.0.4 or newer
    [raven@localhost monodevelop-4.2.3]$
```

Answer (score 2):

The `configure` script reads the mono version via `pkg-config`. Make sure you have the `mono.pc` installed and that your `pkg-config` is finding it. Since you seem to have installed mono into `/usr/local`, chances are that your `mono.pc` is in `/usr/local/lib/pkg-config`. You are however using `pkg-config` from `/usr/bin` which might not be configured to look in `/usr/local`. You should re-run `configure` with the proper directory added to `PKG_CONFIG_PATH`, such as:

```
PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/lib/pkgconfig ./configure
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to install the mono-devel package. I got the tip from this [thread](http://www.linuxquestions.org/questions/linux-newbie-8/missing-the-mono-pc-file-centos-mortadelo-854841/). To install mono-devel I used:

```
$ sudo apt-get install mono-devel
```

Answer (score 1):

compile and install mono with

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr
```

instead of

```
./autogen.sh --prefix=/usr/local
```